# Value of $x$ when $\sum (2+(-1)^n)^n x^n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find all the value of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ when the following series converges :
$$\sum (2+(-1)^n)^n x^n$$

I first thought I can apply the root test,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(2+(-1)^n)^n x^n} &= \sqrt{(2+(-1)^n)^n} \cdot \sqrt{x^n} \\
&= \left| 2+(-1)^n\right| \left| x \right|
\end{align}

By this test, we know that this series converges only if 
$$\left| 2+(-1)^n\right| \left| x \right| \to L < 1$$

Since $1 \le \left| 2+(-1)^n\right| \le 3$, we can conclude that $\left|x\right| < 1$.

But I know the solution and that's not it!

Comment: Is it $\left|x\right|<1/3$?

Comment: Consider even and odd terms separately.

Comment: Sorry I deleted that as I was unsure if the limit had to exist, but it is just the limsup has to be less than 1, so yes, $<1/3$

Comment: But don't forget to check if it converge when $x$ is in the boundary.

Comment: @surb why do I need to test the boundaries?

Comment: Because this test gives you only the convergence in $]-1/3, 1/3[$, but it my converge if $x=1/3$ or $x=-1/3$. Take for exemple $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$, the test convergent will tell you that it converge on $]-1,1[$, but it also converge for $x=-1$.

Comment: @surb ok. Why don't we test other values,  example x>1/3?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is begging you to use the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem for the radius of convergence!

Indeed note that if $a_n = (2 + (-1)^n)^n$ then by Cauchy-Hadamard
$$ \frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{|(2 + (-1)^n)^n|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |2 + (-1)^n| = 3$$
So we must have $R = \frac{1}{3}$.

To check the boundaries consider $x = \frac{1}{3}$ or $x = - \frac{1}{3}$. In the first case
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(2 + (-1)^n)^n}{3^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{N/2} 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \frac{1}{3^{2n + 1}} \geq \sum_{n=0}^{N/2} \to \infty, \ N \to \infty$$
So $x = \frac{1}{3}$ does not work. For the second case $x = - \frac{1}{3}$ we have
$$ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(2 + (-1)^n)^n (-1)^n}{3^n} = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{((-1)^{n+1} - 2)^n}{3^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{N/2} 1 - \sum_{n=1}^{N/2} \frac{1}{3^{2n + 1}} \to \infty, \ N \to \infty$$
So the sum converges for $x \in B(0, 1/3)$.

Note that there are some details missing above such as $N$ being odd or even, but I hope my answer gives you the general idea how to approach these problems, and check all cases!

Comment: Why can we not say that this series converges only if $\left|x\right|<1/3$?

Comment: Can you develop your steps. I can't figure it out how did you develop your sums.

Comment: Sorry about the notation! When I say that $x$ converges for $x \in B(0, 1/3)$ this means that $|x| < 1/3$! As to how to develop the sums. I suggest you simply write out the first 5 terms of the series. You will notice that in the first case all the even terms will leave you with 1 and odd terms with a geometric series. I am sure if you write them out you'll see what is happening!